# C# ConcurrentBag - How to safely clear on every N objects added

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging

I'm implementing a custom logger that logs to AWS CloudWatch and it's is an async logger. The logger works on my WCF service and multiple threads are trying to log at the same time. I've created a thread safe singleton access for the logging to happen but AWS CloudWatch SDK can't send the next log before it finishes sending the current one.

So my idea is to pool the log messages in a ConcurrentBag and once it reaches some N members i will send logs in a batch to CloudWatch (SDK allows this, so it's all good).

The process goes like this : Any thread calls the logger > Logger adds a message to the ConcurrentBag > A sender thread keeps checking the count (or the same one) > If count is >= N send batch log and lock other threads from adding while it's sending > repeat

The process doesn't have to wait for the response to start adding again to the ConcurrentBag.

What would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is something like a backbuffer. Once one bag is full you exchange it in an atomar operation and process it. I've sketches such a class that could handle this:

```
public class DualBag<T> : IDisposable
{
    private ConcurrentBag<T> _bag;
    private int _threshold;
    private ManualResetEventSlim _exchangeEvent;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

    public DualBag(int threshold)
    {
        _bag = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
        _threshold = threshold;
        _exchangeEvent = new ManualResetEventSlim();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(() => Consume());
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        _bag.Add(item);

        if (_bag.Count > _threshold)
        {
            _exchangeEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    private async Task Consume()
    {
        while (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _exchangeEvent.Wait();
            _exchangeEvent.Reset();
            var _replacementBag = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
            var bag = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _bag, _replacementBag);
            await ConsumeBag(bag);
        }

        if (!_bag.IsEmpty)
            await ConsumeBag(_bag);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }

    public Task ConsumeBag(ConcurrentBag<T> bag)
    {
        // post entries to the api
    }
}
```

This can be refined by some points. If you use Stephen Cleary asyncEx library you can use the `AsyncManualResetEvent` to make the processing loop truely async and get rid of a most time blocked thread.

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna try it out and see how it performs!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest ConcurrentQueue for enqueue and dequeue the items. wakeup your service let say 1 min once and dequeue the n number items and added in the List and send to API or elsewhere. So we don't end up locking anything here.